# User can drag a prime ng table row and drop in any of pDroppable div's

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

There is a prime-ng p-table with multiple row's(pDraggable) of information.
And there will be multiple div's to receive(pDroppable) the dragged items.

Flow: A user can drag a row from p-table and drop it to area/box of his liking. The box be more than 1.

Example: from 10 row of data a user will drag 4th row and drop to second box/div among eight box/div created for dropping.